# Specialized Espoir Sport Tires

Tags: tire

Anyone ever use these? I'm getting these as stock on my next bike (700 x 25 on a 2012 Secteur Sport). I've been using Continental GP 4000s for years and love them. Will they be a step down or is it a good tire?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! Could you be more specific? Are you more concerned about speed (rolling resistance, air resistance, weight, etc), durability, comfort, traction, turning, ... ?

Comment: I would be most concerned with rolling resistance, handling, puncture resistance and road feel.  I only ride on dry pavement.

Answer (score 2):

The Continental GP 4000 are a high end road tire, were as Espoir Sport are a middle tier tire. Top end Specialized road tires are [fairly comparable](https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/road-bike-reviews) to Continental (years back Specialized snagged one of Continental’s lead tire guru).

Middle tier tires tend to prioritize price, wear and puncture resistance, while higher end tires tend to prioritize, speed, comfort and handling.

Which is more important is a personal decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the bike from a physical store, ask them what the cost differential would be for going with the Continental GP 4000s. They can always resell the stock tires assuming you haven't ridden the bike yet, although they may not be able to sell them as new (possibly sell them as "open box"). I never understood why bikes come without pedals (bike of a certain calibre anyway), but they just include tires like people have absolutely no preference.  Tires tend to be one of the things that people are the most finicky and religious about, yet you almost never see a bike sold without tires, unless you are at the point where you buy frame and wheels separately.

This doesn't answer which one is better, but gives you an option for getting the tires you are used to. The LBS should be understanding an accommodate  you if you want something that isn't stock on the bike.

Comment: It didn't occur to me to ask my LBS to put on the Continentals.  The next time I am there I will ask them about it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried 2 pairs of Espoir slicks in 2018: 28mm clinchers on my Focus CX bike equipped with Focus' own brand Concept 38mm wheels and 25mm clinchers on my Cannondale Super Six,  with Fast Forward F6 DT240 wheels. I found the tires roll well, are almost bullet-proof and were so tough & well behaved that I could ride my Focus on fast group road rides, and use my Cannondale off road, without encountering problems. The GP4000s might save you a couple of watts rolling resistance, but unless you're Chris Frome I doubt that you'll really notice.

Comment: I've changed my road bike tires from some close-to-noname "mitlas" 23mm tires to Continental Ultra Sport 25mm. The Continental Ultra Sport behave better on small road imperfections (significantly better), shake a bit more on medium road imperfections and I think they roll faster by about 27-to-30 km/h. While this might not look much, it does feel nicer.  
I only ran them for some 30-40km so I can't say anything about puncture resistance, total mileage, ...